# How to Add Extra Rules vs the Previous Row when Ranking SQL?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Let's say I have a table that shows the changes of customer support ticket.

| timestamp | date | status | rank | dense_rank | row_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-03-22 05:03:22 | 2021-03-22 | OPEN | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-03-24 07:10:05 | 2021-03-24 | DECLINED | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 2021-04-04 09:01:10 | 2021-04-24 | DECLINED | 3 | 3 | 3 (at random) |
| 2021-04-04 09:01:10 | 2021-04-24 | OPEN | 3 | 3 | 4 (at random) |

If we take a look at the 3rd and 4th records, they are the same exact timestamp.

And I want to sort this consistently based on the timestamp ascendingly (not row_number because it is at random, not rank and dense rank because it is not going to be ascending)

Now we have an additional rule, such as **a ticket can't have a sequential same status**. In the case of above & incorporating the rule, the sequence of the record should be:

**open (2021-03-22) - declined (2021-03-24) - open (2021-04-24) - declined (2021-04-24)**

Are there any ways to incorporate this additional rule into `rank() over (partition by ... order by ...)`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want this sequence over the entire table, we can try:

```sql
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY timestamp,
                                      CASE status WHEN 'OPEN' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) AS rn
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY timestamp, CASE status WHEN 'OPEN' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END;
```

The second level of the `ORDER BY` clause sorts open records before records of any other status.  If you wanted this sequence repeated for a given set of records within the table, then you would want to add a `PARTITION BY` clause to the call to `ROW_NUMBER`.